# Download full workspace from Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, zip

I am new to jenkins and I have tried downloading a `zip` archive of this [workspace](https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-android/ws/) in jenkins, but I only get a part of it. Source folders like `tensorflow` or `tools` are not present inside the archive. Is this normal ? 
If so, how do I get all of them inside a `zip` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Archive Artifact` plugin, to add your workspace into archive folder which will make it easily down-loadable.

But be aware that, an artifact in the Jenkins sense is the result of a build - the intended output of the build process.

A common convention is to put the result of a build into a build, target or bin directory.

The Jenkins archiver can use globs (target/*.jar) to easily pick up the right file even if you have a unique name per build.

putting a complete workspace into it will take lot of time.